# Issue with Date difference in Event receiver, If updates is coming from JSOM and SSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, jsom, ssom

We are adding item in list with Jsom and SSOM.
Following is the scenario

1. when item is added through SSOM , we have a date field in which date
   is proper. Once item is added , we have an event receiver written
   for applying few validation, (Adding) is the method . Date is shown
   properly.
2. When item is added through JSOM, we have a date field in which date is proper. Once item is added , we have an event receiver written for applying few validation, (Adding) is the method . Date is not shown properly it showing -5 hours in event reciever

While the date is store properly in the list , but the validation written in event reciever fails because of the time difference.
Kindly let me know any pointer to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently.
Browsers handle datetimes including the timezone of the client. You may solve your problem with UTC JavaScript functions or a third party library like moment.js

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You can add some detailed steps of achieving the solution. This seems more like comment rather than answer. Please update your answer.

Comment: @AnkitkumarMalde Detailed steps? This would require a more detailed question. OP states he requires to be pointed in the right direction. Depending on what has to be done and how it's currently done, "detailed steps" may vary a LOT.

Comment: Date is store  properly, my question why is event receiver behaving differently, when date is inserted from SSOM and JSOM

Comment: you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208676/c-sharp-datetime-to-utc-time-without-changing-the-time, nice way to better get the point with timezones. Client-side, a little snippet or moment.js can help a lot too.